# Loop through variables to make regressions

Tags: r, loops, statistics, regression, linear-regression

I am wondering if I can run multiple regressions over this data frame:

```
 Country Years FDI_InFlow_MilUSD FDI_InFlow_percGDP FDI_InStock_MilUSD FDI_OutFlow_MilUSD FDI_OutFlow_percGDP
    1 Netherlands  1990          11063.31               3.52           71827.79           14371.94               34.96
    2     Romania  1990              0.01               0.00               0.01              18.00                0.16
    3 Netherlands  1991           6074.61               1.88           75404.38           13484.54               37.09
    4     Romania  1991             40.00               0.13              44.00               3.00                0.29
    5 Netherlands  1992           6392.10               1.78           73918.54           13153.78               33.15
    6     Romania  1992             77.00               0.37             122.00               4.00                0.38
```

I would like to run the regression over all variables of interest 3:7 in this case(my original data has 10 variables but I think that's enough to get the point of what I want). Also I would like to have the lm results stored in a data frame and also grouped by Country(if that's possible), rather than making 2 dfs for each Country and then looping through them..

Here's an example of a wanted df(this one isn't grouped):

```
#          term   estimate   std.error  statistic      p.value
# 1  (Intercept) -3.2002150 0.256885790 -12.457735 8.141394e-25
# 2 Sepal.Length  0.7529176 0.043530170  17.296454 2.325498e-37
# 3  (Intercept)  3.1568723 0.413081984   7.642242 2.474053e-12
# 4  Sepal.Width -0.6402766 0.133768277  -4.786461 4.073229e-06
# 5  (Intercept) -0.3630755 0.039761990  -9.131221 4.699798e-16
# 6 Petal.Length  0.4157554 0.009582436  43.387237 4.675004e-86
```

Here's and example of desired result: in this case the calculations are for both countries and are just assigned twice for each Country

```
   Country         term     estimate    std.error statistic      p.value
1 Netherlands  (Intercept) -67825.16741 2.229068e+04 -3.042759 3.615586e-03
2 Netherlands GDP_pcap_USD     14.04734 7.908839e-01 17.761576 3.285528e-24
3     Romania  (Intercept) -67825.16741 2.229068e+04 -3.042759 3.615586e-03
4     Romania GDP_pcap_USD     14.04734 7.908839e-01 17.761576 3.285528e-24
```

I used this line of code: `FDI2 %>% group_by(Country) %>% do(tidy(lm(FDI_InStock_MilUSD ~ GDP_pcap_USD, data= FDI2)))`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the following will do what you want. All that is needed is to note that `lm` can fit a multiple regression model and return an object of class `"mlm"`.

```
models <- lm(as.matrix(df1[-(1:2)]) ~ Country + Years, df1)

class(models)
#[1] "mlm" "lm"


smry <- summary(models)
result <- lapply(smry, coef)
result <- do.call(rbind, result)

head(result)
                    Estimate   Std. Error    t value   Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept)     2.294616e+06 1.847179e+06  1.2422273 0.30241037
#CountryRomania -7.804337e+03 1.515033e+03 -5.1512655 0.01418200
#Years          -1.148555e+03 9.277644e+02 -1.2379813 0.30377452
#(Intercept)     6.843108e+02 7.063395e+02  0.9688129 0.40410011
#CountryRomania -2.226667e+00 5.793307e-01 -3.8435157 0.03107572
#Years          -3.425000e-01 3.547662e-01 -0.9654247 0.40554755
```

Comment: Instead of Country and Years those should be the variables 3:7 not 1:2 ... And in this case the data isn't grouped by Country... And I suppose that the model took all the values for both countries.. I didn't said multivariate regression, I said I wanted to run multiple regressions, I mean one for each variable in 3:7, also the independent variable would also be just one in 3:7, not 2 or more... The results should be grouped by Country. I will try to post an example as soon as I get back home

Comment: @RazvanCretu You do **not** want each of the variables 3:7 regressed on `Country` and `Years`?

Comment: Not quite, for a better understanding let's say I want each variable regressed with others in 3:7 including itself, and results should be grouped by Country, if its not grouped the `lm` would take all the data for both countries.. and this irelevant..

Comment: I have edited the original post, I hope this helps. Let me know if encounter problems. I included and example of the desired result but again it has the data calculated for both countries not individualy for each country.  @Rui Barradas